# MySQL Not Reading Full Line

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using the following SQL Script in my IDE DBeaver, MySQL 8.0.21 Linux (Docker Container). Database is in utf8mb4 / utf8mb4_general_ci encodings.

```sql
DELIMITER //
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_line_total
BEFORE INSERT ON LINE
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.LINE_TOTAL = NEW.LINE_UNITS * NEW.LINE_PRICE;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

It seems to be valid SQL, but it is returning the following error, as if it wasn't reading the full line. I can remove tabs, line returns and it will read more or less characters.

```
Error occurred during SQL script execution

Reason:
SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TRIGGER trg_line_total
BEFORE INSERT ON LINE
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.LINE_TO' at line 1
```

I already seemingly fixed this error once today by deleting everything I had in my editor and typing it out from scratch, as if there was some invisible line ending that was messing things up or getting interpreted. I looked in vim and used the `:set list` command and I see are regular line return carriages. What could it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no `ALTER TRIGGER` or `CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER` in Oracle's MySQL. It supports only [`Create Trigger`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-trigger.html) format.

For MariaDB, in version 10.1.4, added support [`CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/create-trigger/) to their drop-in replacement for MySQL.

**If you are sure that trigger doesn't exists**

Use `CREATE` instead of `CREATE OR REPLACE`.

**If you are modifying existing trigger**

I would suggest that the best practice is to lock the table where the trigger lives, so no rows are impacted with the trigger absent. Dropping and adding triggers while a table is locked is allowed.

```
mysql> LOCK TABLES t1 WRITE; -- the next prompt appears once you've obtained the lock
mysql> DROP TRIGGER t1_bi; 
mysql> DELIMITER $$
mysql> CREATE TRIGGER ti_bi BEFORE INSERT ON t1 FOR EACH ROW 
       BEGIN
       ...
       END $$
mysql> DELIMITER ;
mysql> UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Reference: [Modify Existing Trigger Definition in MySQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/78438/is-it-possible-to-modify-an-existing-trigger-definition-in-mysql)